Send Email to two different contact points in Grafana Alerting from one Alert Rule
I have one alert rule. It is working fine. I have set the configuration in such a way that if there is no data or any error then also it will be in a firing state and send an email to one contact point.
Now I want if it is firing in case of an error then send an email to contact point 1 and if it is firing for the matching condition then send an email to contact point 2.
I have tried and searched so far every possible place but couldn't find it. How can I solve this problem?
